# How can I list all files in a directory with timestamps (in a touch compatible format) on Android

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, command-line

For starters, I am on a Nexus 5, on Android 6.0.1 and I am rooted.

Normally, I'd just do this

`find /path -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%Ts %p\n'`

However, it appears that busybox, though it gives a lot of functionality, does not include the printf feature of find.

Is there any way I can do this, or possibly even get a fully functional version of Find?

Answer (score 0):

I found a version of findutils compiled for Android here

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1268589

I did the following.

1. I copied the find binary to my phone
2. I moved it to /data/local/tmp/find
3. `chmod +x /data/local/tmp/find`
4. Ran the find command I wished to run

(I am rooted, but I did not use the `su` command here, so I'm not certain if this requires root or not.  I have an unrooted phone I can test this on later to see if it's still possible in those circumstances.)

I made a shell script to assist with my ultimate goal.

```
cp /sdcard/find.bin /data/local/tmp/find.bin > /dev/null 2>&1
chmod +x /data/local/tmp/find.bin > /dev/null 2>&1
/data/local/tmp/find.bin "$1" -type f -printf 'touch -t %TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM '"'"'%p'"'"'\n'
rm /data/local/tmp/find.bin > /dev/null 2>&1
```

EDIT: This appears to work on an unrooted phone as well!!!!

EDIT2: While this step works, you need to be rooted to change the modification time with touch, so this isn't useful for what would come next.